Retain white spaces in Dropdown in HTML
We have the below dropdown and it populates manually from the user Input.
now if the user is giving multiple spaces in between the words,i can see the spaces are getting ommited.
`
I tried the below CSS also but still not working
<html:select styleId="Id" property="Id" size="1"
                                 styleClass="preserve-space" value="${Form.Id}">
                        <html:option value="">Select a value </html:option>
                        <html:options collection="resultlist" property="id" labelProperty="name"/>
                    </html:select>

<style>
    .preserve-space {    white-space: pre;    font-family: monospace;  /* Helps maintain consistent spacing */  }   /* For better browser compatibility */
    .preserve-space option {    white-space: pre;    -moz-white-space: pre;  /* Firefox */    -webkit-white-space: pre;  /* Chrome/Safari */  }
</style>


Use &nbsp; instead of spaces

@MauricePerry The values are user populated so we are not sure how many spaces would the user gives

To get better answers from HTML/CSS experts, post the client side code rather than the server side source (just open your page in webbrowser, right click, view page source, copy, trim down and paste that).

Use &nbsp; instead of spaces:
<html:select styleId="Id" property="Id" size="1"
        styleClass="preserve-space" value="${Form.Id}">
    <html:option value="">Select a value </html:option>
    <c:forEach items="${resultlist}" var="item">
        <html:option value="${item.id}"><c:out value='${item.name.replace(" ","&nbsp;")}'/></html:option>
    </c:forEach>
</html:select>


This worked.Thank you..!!

HTML collapses multiple spaces by default, maybe you can replace them with a special space character as &nbsp;
You can also use the white-space: pre: style.It works to preserve spaces in text content.
<html:select styleId="Id" property="Id" size="1"
             styleClass="preserve-space" value="${Form.Id}">
    <html:option value="">Select a value</html:option>
    <html:options collection="resultlist" property="id" labelProperty="name"/>
</html:select>

<style>
    .preserve-space {
        white-space: pre;
        font-family: monospace; /* Helps maintain consistent spacing */
    }
</style>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        const select = document.getElementById("Id");
        for (let i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
            select.options[i].text = select.options[i].text.replace(/ /g, '\u00A0');
        }
    };
</script>


This should solve the limitations of applying CSS styles to option tag inside a select.
